# How do I find the solution $y(x)$ for $0 \le x \le \pi$ for this boundary value problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\displaystyle y''+\frac{1}{25}y=\sum \frac{1}{n} \sin(nx)$

$y(0)=y(π)=0$

I know I'm supposed to use $y(x)=\sum B_n \sin(nx)$, and the answer is supposed to be 
$\displaystyle B_n=\frac{1}{n(\frac{1}{25}-n^2)}$, but I have no idea how to get there. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability to format questions using MathJax (see FAQ). Also, you have two equal signs in the problem. Is that what you meant? Regards

Comment: Thank you for catching my typo.  I apologize for the mistake.  The problem should be correct now.  I will check MathJax and correct my question accordingly as soon as possible.

Comment: no problem, we are a self-serve community and help to check and keep things straight! Welcome to the community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's the correct answer. Just plug in your 'test solution'; you'll see that the left side becomes $\Sigma B_n (n^2+\frac{1}{25})\sin(nx)=\Sigma \frac{1}{n}\sin(nx)$. Setting each term equal, we get $B_n=\frac{1}{n^3+n/25}$.
**Edit:**sorry, plugging in you get $\Sigma B_n (-n^2+\frac{1}{25})\sin(nx)$, which then gives you the correct answer.

Comment: You are correct.  I made another typo and did not catch it.  I am very sorry for the mistake...I hope that's the last one I've made on this problem.  I'm sure I would have seen the answer sooner had I not made so many mistakes!  Thank you!

Comment: That's okay, I made an error as well!